# Using a PHP variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am trying to create a random number server side in php and then changing the text of a div to be this random number using javascript.
The issue is I am not sure how to use the variable containing the Random Number (created in PHP) in my javascript. Here is my current code:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $A = 0;

    function Roulette () {      
       $a = 0;
       $b = 36;
    
       global $A;
       $A = rand($a, $b);   //Random Number     
    }

    Roulette();
?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
  function Roul () {
    var a = 0
    var b = 37
    var A = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a)) + a);  //Random Number
    document.getElementById('Rand').innerHTML = A;
  }

  Roul();
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Rand">?</div>
```

I would like to replace the javascript variable `A` with the reference to the PHP variable `$A`

Also I have tried `var A = <?php echo $A; ?>;` however I keeping getting an error

> "Unexpected token <"

Sorry if this worded/coded badly I am still pretty new to all this.

Comment: Wrap your PHP code under double(**"**)/single(**'**) quotes. ```var A = "<?php echo $A; ?>";``` But then your variable will be in form of **string**, you can convert to **interger** accordingly.

Comment: `<script>document.getElementById('Rand').innerHTML = <?= A ?>;</script>`

Comment: Sounds like you tried this in a file that does not get send through the PHP parser to begin with? Then it will still _literally_ read `var A = <?…` in your JS code, and that is of course a syntax error.

Comment: But why use PHP if you have a working version in JS?

Comment: Beware the IE11 bug where `var a = '';` will freeze the browser. Be *absolutely certain* to use `isset($a) && strlen($a) > 0` to ensure that you're passing *something* versus an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP interprets `.php` files. If you put PHP code inside a `.js` file, it will not be interpreted by PHP. There are two common solutions. The first one is to use AJAX to fetch the value after the page has loaded. The simpler way is to insert the value inside the `.php` file. For example:

```
<!-- inside .php file -->
<head>
  ...
  <script>
    window.A = <?php echo json_encode($A); ?>;
  </script>
  ...
</head>
```

This will make sure the value is inserted as a global variable in JavaScript, and will be usable by your `.js` file. Using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) ensures that the generated JavaScript will be correct for any basic value type.

Another way that is sometimes used is to insert the value as a text content, or an attribute value, of a HTML element:

```
<script id="A" type="application/json"><?php echo json_encode($A); ?></script>
```

then pull it out with JavaScript:

```
const A = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('A').textContent);
```

Yet another way, quite suboptimal, is to make a `.js.php` file, making sure the `ContentType` header is correct and that caching is disabled (don't do this though).

Comment: changing the file to a .php works when I use the var A = <?php echo $A; ?>; thanks!

Comment: It works, but it is a very bad idea, since you have to disable caching to do it correctly, which means the JS file needs to be preprocessed and transmitted each time. It's the easiest solution and I wrote it for completeness sake; there are scenarios where this might be a good idea, but I have not had one yet.